# Bootstrap modal change text in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Okay, I've searched and tried a couple of methods but none work.

I have a modal with forms and a select-options form. I also have normal plain text which I want to change in my jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> <center> Kupovina online </center></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Ime i Prezime:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Adresa:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Telefon:</label>
                <div id="thisIsanID"> <p> THIS TEXT NEEDS TO CHANGE </p> </div>
              </div>

              <label for="paketizaberi" class="control-label">Paket:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="paketizaberi">
                <option value="PaketZvezda">Zvezda</option>
                <option value="PaketSunce">Sunce</option>
                <option value="PaketGalaksija">Galaksija</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Otkaži</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" action="Update.php">Naruči</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And in my jQuery I tried:

```
$('#thisIsanID').find('p').html('Changed Text !!!!!');
```

(This is called when a button is clicked and an option is selected)

What am I missing ?

Comment: It should work. try below code $('#thisIsanID p').html('changed...')

Comment: The jQuery you have should be changing the text, the issue is likely with how  you are calling this bit of code. What does the button onClick event look like?

Comment: this code works fine, see if your button click and option selection are handled properly

Comment: Where do you bind the event to the button and option events?

Comment: all of the above plus try a `console.log('something')` next to the place you call your jQuery code and see if it triggers, chances are it doesn't, so you'll see why... go through that bit of code line by line and you'll find it...

Comment: check console and see if there are any js errors like `$ not found` etc?

Answer (score -1):

add jquery.min file on your script

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```